# Hotswap with Hybris SAP Commerce on Apple silicon

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hotswap

I am trying to use Hotswap on an Apple silicon laptop. After configuring it, when I start the server I get below error. Did someone find a workaround for this? Thanks!

> Launching a JVM... 
> JVM exited while loading the application.
> Error: dl failure on line 560
> Error: failed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dcevm/libjvm.dylib, because dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dcevm/libjvm.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dcevm/libjvm.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
> Reloading Wrapper configuration...
> JVM process is gone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

issue you have is related using different architecture of java used for building code using ant and different used for running it. That issue is well known just google text below.

(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')